# Can Emacs be set up to display Python code in Python mode and display docstrings in ReST mode?

Tags: emacs, python, restructuredtext

I often edit Python code in my Emacs and have it set up to display Python files in Python mode. I often find myself formatting dosctrings as ReStructured Text and I was thinking that it would be great if I could have Emacs show these docstrings as in ReST mode. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Did you have a look at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes ?

Comment: For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493342/have-emacs-edit-python-docstrings-using-rst-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this minor mode

https://github.com/glyph/python-docstring-mode

with that conf:

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/python-docstring-mode-master")
(require 'python-docstring)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda () (python-docstring-mode t)))
```

Comment: I have tried installing python-docstring via `package`. It seems to install OK but is nowhere to be found afterwards and gives an error when I try `require`ing it.

Comment: I don't use `package` but you can download and unzip it in `/path/to/python-docstring-mode-master` to have a try